# Loading a blog post in phonegap iOS app...Youtube videos won't embed

Tags: ios, json, cordova, youtube, yql

I've seen some other similar questions, but haven't quite found my answer. I created an iOS phonegap app that loads blog posts from a desktop site using YQL and JSON. It works well, except that if the original post had a Youtube video embedded, in my app, I get a gray square with a Youtube logo and a play button with a slash through it.

When I load the desktop site in Mobile Safari, however, the embedded clip appears as a still image that links to the mobile friendly version of the clip. The videos are embedded in the desktop site with OBJECT tags. My first assumption was that I needed to list "www.youtube.com" as an ExternalHost, but that hasn't worked. I also tried embedding Youtube videos in the desktop site using iFrames to see if they would embed properly when I call them through the app, but that has not worked either.

Any ideas from you fine folks would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: that's probably done by the client's javascript code - you'll need to implement the same functionality yourself if you want that in your app...

Answer (score 0):

I think the YouTube embedded video's use Flash and well there is no Flash on iOS devices.

Comment: Sorry, I updated the question. When I load the desktop site (which I'm pulling the data from for the app) in Mobile Safari in iOS, the Flash embedded Youtube clip is automatically converted to an image thank links to the mobile friendly version. It does not do that when I use a JSON call to pull the HTML into the app.